# Getting the date only in Convert.ToDateTime() in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, .net-3.5

I have a parameter string that passes date value to a stored proc

```
cmdItemSearch.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
cmdItemSearch.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

The value being passed is "6/30/2010 7:45:00 AM"

I want to pass only "6/30/2010"
How would I do that?

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTinm.Now)` is redundant, since DateTime.Now is a DateTime instance.  Its like saying `"Hello world".ToString()"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, `DateTime.Now` is already a `DateTime` so doesn't need to be converted as you have.

Secondly, you can obtain just the date of Today by using `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`.

However, if your date isn't "today" then you can just use `yourDateTime.Date` to return just the Date.

Comment: when I hover over the word "value", I see "6/30/2010 12:00:00 AM"
How can I be sure it is passing the date only, and not the time as well?

Comment: Well, your StoredProc is passing a Sql DateTime which will always have a time as well anyway. Your stored procedure will need to deal with this.

If you have SQL Server 2008 then you can just use the Date datatype instead.

Comment: @DotNetRookie: You can't, .NET doesn't have a date-only type. The convention for representing date-only is setting the time component to midnight.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the mm/dd/yyyy format, you could use

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
```

That will return the short format, but depends on the current culture

Comment: That returns a `string`, not a `DateTime`.

Comment: True, but I figured that someone may be looking to get just the short date string, so I included it

Answer (score 1):

```
cmdItemSearch.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Note that the [`Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) property simply returns a `DateTime` with the time element set to midnight.

Comment: DateTime.Now.Date is the same as DateTime.Today

Comment: @Robin: Was just making that change when you commented!

Answer (score 0):

MSDN to the rescue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 6, 1, 7, 47, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString());

// Get date-only portion of date, without its time.
DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;
// Display date using short date string.
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("d"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a variable called EndDate

var EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);

Now EndDate  Type is DateTime;

you pass it as a  parameter

cmdItemSearch.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = EndDate  ;